# mongoid references_many referenced_in not working rails

Tags: associations, mongoid

I have a problem with referenced_many and referenced_in relation model.
My model is of following.
Student references_many mobile_numbers
MobileNumber referenced_in Student

Now when i try to do
@mobile = MobileNumber.first
@mobile.student

It pops error saying
Document not found for class Student with id(s) 4c47e74ff1936f05f9000015

And @mobile object has student_id : "4c47e74ff1936f05f9000015" as one of its attribute

Is there any thing wrong with my data or with my model
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of Mongoid. I believe older version used `has_many_related` and `belongs_to_related`.